# Get the value of an attribute from webbrowser1

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control, getelementsbytagname, getattribute

I have the following code which extracts all URLS within Google's search results:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HtmlElementCollection a = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a");
        foreach (HtmlElement b in a)
        {
            string item = b.GetAttribute("href");
            if (item.Contains("url?q=")) 
            {
            listBox1.Items.Add(item);
                }
        }
    }
```

However I need this to be more specific.

Google's Chrome element inspector has this and I need to access the URL in this element:

```
<cite class="_Rm">www.dicksmith.com.au/apple-<b>ipad</b></cite>
```

The class is "_Rm", its in a 'cite' tag, and I need that URL ONLY.

Answer (score 0):

Find html element with specified 'class' and 'tag' values. Then retrieve an url from InnerHtml.

```
HtmlElement FindHtmlElement(string tag, Predicate<HtmlElement> predicate)
{
    try
    {            
        var elements = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName(tag);
        foreach (HtmlElement element in elements)
        {
            if (predicate(element))
            {
                return element;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //Log.Error("Error on finding html element on {0}. Exception: {1}", _webBrowserBot.Url.ToString(), ex.Message);
    }

    return null;

}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // search for <cite class="_Rm">www.dicksmith.com.au/apple-<b>ipad</b></cite>
    var element = FindHtmlElement("cite", (h) =>
    {
        return h.GetAttribute("class") == "_Rm";               
    });

    string url = "";
    if (element != null)
    {
        // retrieve url only
        int ix = element.InnerHtml.IndexOf("-<b>");
        if (ix > 0)
            url = element.InnerHtml.Remove(ix);

        // url obtained
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi there, I tried to apply the above code, and where it says: // URL OBTAINED, I tried to enter it into the listbox1, but its not doing anything, not sure what is happening... thanks for your help anyway, much appreciated